# how to search integer type by text value in yii model search

Tags: php, yii

I have a field with name "`author_id`" in `Document` model. I want to search some records in `admin` page via `advanced search`. But, I want `author_id` field can be filled by text value. How can  I do this?

This is `Document` model:

```
public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('title, content', 'required'),
        array('author_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('title, content, author_id', 'safe'),

        array('title, content, author_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}


public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'author_id'),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'content' => 'Content',
        'author_id' => 'Author',
    );
}

public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->pertanyaan,true);
    $criteria->compare('content',$this->penanya_id, true);
    $criteria->compare('author_id',$this->author_id);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

And this is `_search.php` in my view.

```
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
        'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
        'method'=>'get',
    )); ?>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php echo $form->textFieldGroup($model,'title', array('widgetOptions'=>array('htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span8')))); ?>

            <?php echo $form->textAreaGroup($model,'content', array('widgetOptions'=>array('htmlOptions'=>array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'class'=>'span8')))); ?>

            <?php echo $form->textFieldGroup($model,'author_id',array('widgetOptions'=>array('htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span5')))); ?>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer clearfix no-border pull-right">
            <?php $this->widget(
                'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
                array(
                    'encodeLabel'=>false,
                    'buttonType' => 'submit',
                    'label' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Document!',
                    'context' => 'primary',
                )
            ); ?>
            <?php $this->widget(
                'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
                array('buttonType' => 'reset', 'label' => 'Reset')
            ); ?>

       </div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Thank You :)

Comment: It 's you need to search by author name?

Comment: @YatinMistry: Yes. I want to seach by author name. And your answer is very helpful for me. it works! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Document model,

Add author_name for search criteria in `rules()`

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...,
        array('title, content, author_id,author_name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

    );
}
```

`Search()` function,

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->pertanyaan,true);
    $criteria->compare('content',$this->penanya_id, true);
    $criteria->compare('author_id',$this->author_id);

    // Add search on author name
    $criteria->with = array('author','author2');

    $criteria->compare('auther_name',$this->author_id);

    $criteria->compare('auther_name2',$this->author_id2);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: It worked for 1 relation. How about 2 relations or many with same reference table?

for example, The document have 2 authors. Then I put:
`$criteria->with = array('author2');
    $criteria->compare('auther_name',$this->author2_id);`
and it didn't work